# Puppeteer not allowing me to run multiple functions in different blocks of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, puppeteer

I'm in the process of making an Autocheckout bot, I'm attempting to make the section that checks if the item is in stock and I want to make it all different functions in different code blocks. The problem is I cant get it to run.
When I wrap the function in () only the first function runs while the second one does nothing.

Here is the code without the () around the functions, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
const puppeteerExtra = require('puppeteer-extra');
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const rand_url = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Cyberpunk-2077-Warner-Bros-PlayStation-4/786104378";

async function initBrowser(){ 

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--incognito"],headless:false}); //Launches browser in incognito
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage(); //Ensures the new page is also incognito
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;});
    await page.goto(rand_url); //goes to given link
    return page;
   
};

    async function checkstock(page){
    await page.reload();
    let content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)
    $("link[itemprop ='availability']", content).each(function(){
       let out_of_stock = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().includes("outofstock");
       if(out_of_stock){
           console.log("Out of Stock");
           
       } else{
           await browser.close();
           console.log("In Stock")
            //await page.waitForSelector("button[class='button spin-button prod-ProductCTA--primary button--primary']", {visible: true,}); //Waits for Add to Cart Button
            //await page.$eval("button[class='button spin-button prod-ProductCTA--primary button--primary']", elem => elem.click()); //Clicks Add to cart button
       }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute the code do it as follow, but you will get ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
const puppeteerExtra = require('puppeteer-extra');
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const rand_url = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Cyberpunk-2077-Warner-Bros-PlayStation-4/786104378";

async function initBrowser(){ 

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--incognito"],headless:false}); //Launches browser in incognito
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage(); //Ensures the new page is also incognito
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;});
    await page.goto(rand_url); //goes to given link
    return page;
};
 

async function checkstock(page){
    await page.reload();
    let content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)
    console.error(content);
    $("link[itemprop ='availability']", content).each(async function(){ 
 
       let out_of_stock = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().includes("outofstock");
       if(out_of_stock){
           console.log("Out of Stock");
           
       } else{

        await browser.close();
       }
    });
};

(async () => {
    const page = await initBrowser()
    await checkstock(page)
})()
```

Comment: Yep, that helped me with getting the blocks to run! Thanks for the help! Nothing I read mentioned having that async function at the end. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You only was declaring the functions but you didn't was calling it to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code, and after add to launch.json:

"outputCapture": "std"

I noticed that there is an error in the following line:

await browser.close();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

You need to add async

```
$("link[itemprop ='availability']", content).each(async function(){
```

Comment: I still cant seem to launch it. On my end I get that my functions are declared but their values are never read. The way I can fix that is by doing (async function initBrowser(){})() but when I do that I can't get the second function, the check stock one, to work.